# Twitter bootstrap navbar button color changes on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Twitter bootstrap website I have a navbar. It has buttons on it.
I add "btn-success" or "btn-danger" classes to them for color markup.
I make this because when user changes theme (css) buttons is shown with respect to [that theme](http://bootswatch.com/).

I use `navbar-inverse`. So background is black. I change button link's color to white. But the problem is when user hovers on button, button becomes transparent and the color can't be read.

So I need navbar buttons to be visible, even user hovers on it. I want button color to be same when hover or not.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/4RhhF/15/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="padding-top: 15px;"> 
            <a href="/page0" style="color:#ffffff;margin-top:40px;">Example.com</a>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" style="color:#000" href="#">
                    <span>MyButton is very good</span>
                </a>    
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-success" style="color:#000" href="#">
                    <span>MyButton is very good 2</span>
                </a>    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: sir, you've got an an-swer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the following in your custom css file:

```css
/* This would be for the danger button... */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.btn-danger:hover {
    background-color: #d9534f;
}

/* ...and this one for the success button */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.btn-success:hover {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

You're basically manually re-coloring the background color of each button on hover.

Here is **[your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RhhF/18/)**.